# web2py SQLFORM.grid parameter definitions

Tags: python, web2py

The web2py grid/smartgrid documentation  documentation has a long list of parameters, but a sparse description of them.  For example, the fields parameter just says

> fields is a list of fields to be fetched from the database.

but how are the fields supposed to be named?  Are there examples of grid and smartgrid that show the actual use of the grid/smartgrid parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same as they would be named in a database query.  (That may sound flip, but its as direct as I can be.)

Here's an example of using grid w/ at least some of the parameters: http://www.web2pyslices.com/slices/take_slice/148

Answer (score 1):

ex:

```
fields=[db.table1.f1, db.table1.f2]
```